# Google Drive fails to add calendar event invitees as editors of a document and send an email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Building off of another project, I wanted to automate the creation and distribution of a Google Sheet for a recurring calendar event. I was able to test my code successfully when two of my own personal email addresses were the calendar event invitees, but when deploying it on an event with a dozen coworkers, it failed to run, returning `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Internal Error`

The Google Apps Script below looks for specific text in a Google Calendar event descrption that week and if it is found will copy a template file and rename it for that day, storing it in the appropriate month and year folder.

```
/**
 * When there is a change to the calendar, searches for events that include "#meetingagenda"
 * in the decrisption.
 *
 */
function onCalendarChange() {
  // Gets recent events with the #meetingagenda tag
  const now = new Date();
  const dayOfWeek = now.getDay();
  
  // Check if it is Monday (dayOfWeek = 1) and if it is not a holiday (e.g., Christmas Day)
  if (dayOfWeek === 1) {
        // Calculate the start of the current week (Sunday)
        const startOfWeek = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() - dayOfWeek);
  
        // Calculate the end of the current week (Saturday)
        const endOfWeek = new Date(startOfWeek.getTime() + 6 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        
    const events = CalendarApp.getEvents(
        startOfWeek,
        endOfWeek,
        {search: '#meetingagenda'},
    );


    // Loops through any events found
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      const event = events[i];

      // Confirms whether the event has the #meetingagenda tag
      let description = event.getDescription();
      if (description.search('#meetingagenda') == -1) continue;
    
      const eventDate = Utilities.formatDate(event.getStartTime(), "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy");
        
        // Get the year from the event date
        const year = eventDate.split("-")[2];
        
        // Get the month number from the event date
        const monthNum = eventDate.split("-")[0];
        
        // Get the month name from the month number
        const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
        const month = monthNames[parseInt(monthNum, 10) - 1];


  /**
  * Checks to see if there is a folder for the year the event takes place. If not, it creates one.
  * Then checks to see if there is a folder for the month that the event takes place. If not, it creates one.
  *
  */
        // Get the root folder
        var rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("FOLDER_WHERE_THE_FILES_GET_STORED");
        
        // Check if the year folder exists
        var yearFolder = rootFolder.getFoldersByName(year);
        if (yearFolder.hasNext()) {
          yearFolder = yearFolder.next();
        } else {
          // Create the year folder
          yearFolder = rootFolder.createFolder(year);
        }
        
        // Check if the month folder exists
        var monthFolder = yearFolder.getFoldersByName(month);
        if (monthFolder.hasNext()) {
          monthFolder = monthFolder.next();
        } else {
          // Create the month folder
          monthFolder = yearFolder.createFolder(month);
        }

// Only works with events created by the owner of this calendar
if (event.isOwnedByMe()) {
  // Creates a new sheet from the template file and renames it for this event's date
  const templateSheetId = "_FILE_ID_FOR_THE_TEMPLATE_SHEET";
  const newSheet = DriveApp.getFileById(templateSheetId).makeCopy("Meeting Agenda " + eventDate, monthFolder);
  const newSheetId = newSheet.getId();
  console.log(newSheetId);

  // Replaces the hashtag in the event description with a link to the agenda sheet
  const agendaUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + newSheetId;
  let description = event.getDescription();
  description = description.replace('#meetingagenda', '<a href=' + agendaUrl + '>Meeting Agenda</a>');
  event.setDescription(description);
```

**The step where (I think) it fails** is when it tries to use the [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) to make all event invitees Editors of the newly created file and send the notifying message with some custom text ([based in part on this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70775595/adding-message-to-email-when-using-addeditor)).

I definitely enabled the Advanced Drive Service, but it seems the error is tied to that failing, right? My syntax matches the documentation and the previous example. Is there something additional that I'm missing for the Advanced Drive service to function?

```
  // Adds event invitees as editors of the new sheet
  const editors = event.getGuestList().filter(guest => guest.getEmail() !== "").map(guest => guest.getEmail());
  Drive.Permissions.insert({
     role: 'writer',
     type: 'user',
     value: editors 
     }, 
     
     newSheetId, 
     { 
       'sendNotificationEmails': 'true',
       'emailMessage': "Hi everyone, Attached here is the agenda for this week's meeting. Please take a few minutes between now and then to note some high-level projects and tasks which you worked on last week and some that you are tackling this week." });
  }
}
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76166474/17926478) answer actually worked for you (at least for your initial concern), don't forget to either upvote or mark it as 'best answer'. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the script to add editors to the file and it worked, the only issue I found is that it only adds one editor. The limitation with the `Drive.Permissions.insert()` method,  is that you can only share files with one user at a time. I modified the script to this:

```js
// Adds event invitees as editors of the new sheet
        const editors = event.getGuestList().filter(guest => guest.getEmail() !== "").map(guest => guest.getEmail());
        editors.forEach(editor =>{
          Drive.Permissions.insert({
            role: 'writer',
            type: 'user',
            value: editor
            },
            
            newSheetId, 
            {
              sendNotificationEmails: 'true',
              emailMessage: "Hi everyone, Attached here is the agenda for this week's meeting. Please take a few minutes between now and then to note some high-level projects and tasks which you worked on last week and some that you are tackling this week."
            }
          )}
        )
      }
  
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

This is just a sample, just take in consideration if the list of editors is too long, more API calls are made and you will reach the limit.

Another workaround is to use batch requests, you can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60860212/17926478) for more details. I used the "Pattern 2" and it works. When batch request is used, more API calls can be done by one API call.

```js
// Adds event invitees as editors of the new sheet
        const editors = event.getGuestList().filter(guest => guest.getEmail() !== "").map(guest => guest.getEmail());
        const reqs = editors.map(e => ({
          method: "POST",
          endpoint: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + newSheetId + "/permissions?supportsAllDrives=true&emailMessage=Hi%20everyone%2C%20Attached%20here%20is%20the%20agenda%20for%20this%20week%27s%20meeting.%20Please%20take%20a%20few%20minutes%20between%20now%20and%20then%20to%20note%20some%20high-level%20projects%20and%20tasks%20which%20you%20worked%20on%20last%20week%20and%20some%20that%20you%20are%20tackling%20this%20week.&sendNotificationEmails=true",
          requestBody: {role: "writer", type: "user", emailAddress: e},
        }));
        
        const requests = {batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests: reqs};
        const res = BatchRequest.Do(requests);
        console.log(res.getContentText());
      }  
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

## References:

- [API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Internal Error](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/WyQR5K_L4yM)
- [BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install)
- [Share Files with Multiple Users](https://www.labnol.org/code/google-drive-share-files-2108261#share-files-with-multiple-users)

Comment: I had a feeling that there might be a limitation with adding an unlimited number of editors. It would make sense that `Drive.Permissions.insert()` is the culprit. Adding that `editors.forEach(editor =>{` would make a ton of sense. Got the next meeting to apply it to next week, so I'll see how it goes then. Thank you!

Comment: `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Internal Error` was my error this morning. Seems like the same issue reoccurred. Wish there was more detail than that to work with from those "Summary of failures" emails