# https://www.googleapis.com/batch returns error 404

Tags: google-apps-script, http-status-code-404, urlfetch, batch-request

I was trying to create Apps Script web app, which would allow me to share multiple files with multiple users using a solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859530/drive-permissions-insert-value-drive-api-can-you-use-an-array-under-value/60860212?r=Saves_UserSavesList#60860212)

Whenever I tried running the function provided within the linked solution above (the first solution using UrlFetchApp) it always ended in error (code 404)

From the Logger and debugger, i can see that it has trouble reaching the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` sequence.

Snippets of my GS Script with only minor modifications from the original link provided above:

```js
var userEmailsArray = ["email@mail.com"]; // sample placeholder
var fileId = "File-ID"; // sample placeholder
function changePermissionBatch(role = "reader", type = "user") {
    const resources = userEmailsArray.map(e => ({role: role, type: type, emailAddress: e}));
    const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    const payload = resources.reduce((s, e, i) => {
      s += "Content-Type: application/http\r\n" +
        "Content-ID: " + i + "\r\n\r\n" +
        "POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "/permissions?sendNotificationEmails=false" + "\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n" +
        JSON.stringify(e) + "\r\n" +
        "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
      return s;
    }, "--" + boundary + "\r\n");
    const params = {
      method: "post",
      contentType: "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary,
      payload: payload,
      headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    };
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/batch", params);
    console.log(res.getContentText())
  }
```

Am I missing something here, or are there any recent policies / updates which may cause the request to fail that I may not be aware of?

The logs provided aren't of much help either since it's a shortened HTTP response, and I've looked around and found no way to conclude what was wrong based on those logs, and I'm basically at a loss here.

Comment: Upon checking https://www.googleapis.com/batch is already depecrated.

Comment: Hi @Logan thanks for pointing it out, i thought that might be the case.

I just couldn't fine the documentation. Would you mind directing me to the source documentation link, just to avoid similar problems in the future, and hopefully further questions from me won't be a simple deprecated issues :"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks to Logan for pointing out the deprecated section. I went out and found a blog post by Tanaike (the person who provided the solution within my referenced link on my original question)

**changed and updated the following line** from:

```
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/batch", params);
```

**into**:

```
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3", params);
```

The function now works as intended, and the log returns no errors, so problem solved.

**Source:**

[Link 1](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/efficient-file-management-using-batch-requests-google-apps-script) - Blog Post with sample line containing the specific batchPath required for the code to work

[Link 2](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html) - Official doc / announcements of the issue